# How can I use a gRPC client in a Sublime Text plugin?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, grpc

How might I use a gRPC client in a Sublime Text plugin? The [gRPC docs](http://www.grpc.io/docs/installation/python.html) only talk about using venv, but that isn't what I want to do if I'm writing a Sublime Text plugin (right?).

And beyond just getting something running, how will I package it to run anywhere? Is gRPC a bad fit for this kind of thing?

(I'm a python novice.)

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: gRPC includes native components so it's a poor choice for a Sublime plugin.

Comment: @Adam Write a server in C++ and communicate with it from a Sublime Text plugin. It's a remote editing tool. gRPC attracted me because it handles so much of the work from the C++ side (I'm a C++ noob too). Looks like I may end up just using a simple HTTP server and sending JSON back and forth. I'm mostly trying to minimize the amount of code I have to write, especially handling shoddy network conditions.